# error on part of code that shouldn't trigger in the firts place

Tags: python, python-3.x, class, boolean, typeerror

Tl;dr in my "variable" class, upon creating a new instance, I make it do a fuction called `check()` to see if there are any variables of the same type within itself, so it can then simplify it, yet somehow I get a bool error for something that should only occour if the data used in that part of the `__new__` fuction is not `False` and the data can never be `True`, yet the pieces of code before where the error occours don't trigger

So, I've been making this python class that represents a variable you don't know the value of, and was working on making the class atau-simplify it's own value if at all possible,  and got some very weird results;

```
class variable:
    def __new__(cls, name = "x", value = 1, power = 1):
        self = object.__new__(cls)
        self.name = name
        if value == 0:
            return 0
        if name == "" and value == 1:
            return 1
        if name == "" and not isinstance(power, variable):
            return value**power
        else:
            self.power = power
            self.value = value
        if not isinstance(self.value, variable):
            return self
        global check
        check = self.value.check(name)
        print(repr(check))
        if check == False:
            return self
        new = ""
        for x in check[1:-1]:
            new += "variable(x.name, "
        if isinstance(check[-1].value, str):
            new += "'" + check[-1].value + "'"
        else:
            new += repr(check[-1].value)
        for x in list(reversed(check[1:-1])):
            new += repr(x.power) + ")"
        print("'")
        print(new)
        print(self)
        print("'")
        if new == None:
            new = 1
        return variable(self.name, eval(new), self.power + check[-1].power)

    def check(self, name):
        if self.name == name:
            return [self,]
        if isinstance(self.value, variable):
            if not self.value.check(name) == False:
                return self.value.check(name).insert(0, self)
        return False
    def __str__(self):
        return (not self.value == 1)*str(self.value) + (not self.power == 1)*"(" + str(self.name) + (not self.power == 1)*(")^" + str(self.power))
    def __repr__(self):
        if isinstance(self.value, str):
            return "variable('" + self.name + "', '" + self.value + "', " + repr(self.power) + ")"
        return "variable('" + self.name + "', " + repr(self.value) + ", " + repr(self.power) + ")"
    def __add__(self, other):
        if isinstance(other, variable) and (self.name == other.name and self.power == other.power):          
            return variable(other.name, self.value + other.value, other.power)
        else:
            return NotImplemented
    def __sub__(self, other):
        if isinstance(other, variable) and (self.name == other.name and self.power == other.power):          
            return variable(other.name, self.value - other.value, other.power)
        else:
            return NotImplemented
    def __mul__(self, other):
        if isinstance(other, variable) and self.name == other.name:
            return variable(self.name, self.value*other.value, self.power+other.power)
        elif isinstance(other, int) or isinstance(other, float) or isinstance(other, variable):
            return variable(self.name, self.value*other, self.power)
        else:
            return NotImplemented
    def __truediv__(self, other):
        if isinstance(other, variable) and self.name == other.name:
            return variable(self.name, self.value/other.value, self.power-other.power)
        elif isinstance(other, int) or isinstance(other, float) or isinstance(other, variable):
            return variable(self.name, self.value/other, self.power)
        else:
            return NotImplemented
    def __pow__(self, other):
        if isinstance(other, int) or isinstance(other, float) or isinstance(other, variable):
            return variable(self.name, self.value**other, self.power*other)
        else:
            return NotImplemented
    __radd__ = __add__
    __rsub__ = __sub__
    __rmul__ = __mul__
    def __rtruediv__(self, other):
        return other**(self**-1)  
    def __rpow__(self, other):
        if isinstance(other, variable):
            return variable(other.name, other.value**self, other.power*self)
        elif isinstance(other, int) or isinstance(other, float):
            return variable("", other, self)
        else:
            return NotImplemented
```

I entered;

```
>>> variable("x", variable("y", variable("z", variable("y", variable("y", variable("z", variable("x")))))))
```

Result;

```
False
False
[variable('y', variable('z', variable('x', 1, 1), 1), 1)]
'
variable('z', variable('x', 1, 1), 1)
xzyy
'
False
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<pyshell#34>", line 1, in <module>
    variable("x", variable("y", variable("z", variable("y", variable("y", variable("z", variable("x")))))))
  File "C:\Users\Alexander van Helm\Desktop\Python\herleiden.py", line 62, in __new__
    return variable(self.name, eval(new), self.power + check[-1].power)
TypeError: 'bool' object is not subscriptable
```

Comment: Why are you making `check` global (I strongly suspect this is your issue)? Also, why are you returning the result of `insert()` in your `check()` method, which always returns `None`?

Comment: Oh. I thought `.insert(0, arg)` did the opposite of `.append(arg)`.

Comment: I see my error now.

Comment: I'm supposed to insert the list itself appearently.

Comment: That doesn't change anything about the error I was geting though.

Comment: Remove the `global check`, and I think you'll find your code works. I believe your call `eval(new)` invokes `variable.__new__()`, which in turn sets your global variable `check` to `False`, after you've checked it.

Comment: Ah. I'll try that. I added the `global check` for debugging purposes in the first place :)

Comment: That worked, can you post it as an answer so I can accept it?

Comment: @dlasalle You should post that as an answer.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Remove the `global check`, and I think you'll find your code works. I believe your call `eval(new)` invokes `variable.__new__()`, which in turn sets your global variable `check` to `False`, after you've checked it.

(comment turned answer)

Answer (score 0):

`check[-1].power` in your return statement `return variable(self.name, eval(new), self.power + check[-1].power)` is the problem.

The `check()` method returns a `bool`. Which means it can only be one of two things`False` or `True`. You can't do an operation like this `check[-1]` on `bool` type. That is what the TypeError 
`TypeError: 'bool' object is not subscriptable` trys to tell you

Comment: I can see that. The thing is, if you look at the code, it can never reach that point if it is a bool.